# How to connect Chrome Extension to Youtube Analytics API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, youtube, google-api

I'm trying to use oAuth to connect a Chrome extension to the Youtube Analytics API. I've followed the following guide: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html, but the request keeps on giving me a 400 Bad Request error.

I also tried following this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application, but in Google APIs Console, you cannot set the oAuth redirect to a Chrome Extension.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/

Using the API there fixed everything.